# regular expression: plus character

Tags: regex

Finally started learning some regex.
This is probably a stupid question, but what would be the difference between

```
tre+
```

and

```
tre
```

If it finds it, it matches, right?

Edit: currently reading this tutorial: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

Comment: `tre+` matches `tre` OR `tree` or `treee` i.e. 1 or more `e`'s after `tr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference may be significant depending on how you're using the regular expression. If you're just testing whether a string matches the regexp, the `+` is redundant. But if you're using it to perform a substitution, e.g. `preg_replace` in `PHP` or `s/regexp/replacement/` in `Perl` or `sed`, using the `+` will cause it to replace the longest matching substring.

For example, if your input string is:

```
Cut down the trees
```

and you do:

```
s/tre/foo/
```

the result will be:

```
Cut down the fooes
```

But if you do:

```
s/tre+/foo/
```

the result will be:

```
Cut down the foos
```

Comment: Ooh that's the reason. Well, I have to accept one, the 'replace' case made it clear so I'll accept your answer. Should have been obvious, but I'm new to do this so I didn't immediately see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

- `tre+`  Matches `tr` plus the following  one or more `e`'s.
- `tre` Matches the string `tre`

Comment: According to this post: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm, tree would also be found with tre  --> Is that incorrect or what am I missing? (simple matching)

Comment: @KimGysen: That depends on how you're performing the regex match. For example, in Java, the `.matches()` method only succeeds if the input matches the regex entirely.

Comment: then add word boundaries to match only `tre` like `\btre\b`. see http://regex101.com/r/mN8kN0/2

Comment: Ok, but that's why I wondered about the difference. I'm not looking for a match, just trying to understand. Is tre+ also found with preceding characters? I can't seem to see the difference between them..., well I don't get the use of the '+'.

Comment: `tre` matches only tre. That is in the string `tree`, the regex `tre` matches the first `tre` but the regex `tre+` matches the whole string `tree` because `e+` is found at the last.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't tell which regex flavor you were using.

for **BRE** (Basic Regular Expressions):

```
tre+ matches string: "tre+"
tre  matches string: "tre"
```

for **ERE/PCRE** (Extended Regular Expressions/Perl Compatible Regular Expressions):  Avinash answered it already.

```
tre+ matches string: "tre" or "tree" or "treeeeeee" 
tre  matches string: "tre"
```

Answer (score 1):

`tre+` matches `tr` with one or more `a` following. `tre` matches just `tre`.

If you just check if the string matches, they will match the same strings. The difference starts when you are interested in knowing which part of the string matched. For instance if the entire string matched, or when you want to capture the matched part.

Comment: +1 Thanks, indeed. I accepted Barmar's because he was first. But this explanation is also very clear. Somehow I didn't see it, but now it's obvious.